# max dates per item

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an invoice table whereby I need to see the last 5 invoice dates per stock code.
I used Top 5 max(date), but this only gave me the top 5 dates for the entire table and not per stock code. 
Please could someone help? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Select * from (
    Select Code,date ,row_number() over(partition by Code order by date Desc) rowNumber
 ) t where rowNumber<=5
```